# How do I fetch profile info from facebook using OAuth plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am using OAuth plugin for my Grails project for user to log in to my page. I am integrating facebook,google,and linkedIn to my web app. The OAuth plugin uses springSecurityOAuth plugin and respective OAuth plugins for facebook, google and linkedIn.
 But the plugin is only fetching the userId from the social sites while I need to extract other profile info like firstname, lastname email etc. How can I achieve this?

I have already got required permissions for email and public_profile from facebook.

UPDATE:: I manually wrote code to get info such as firstname, lastname etc from providers. I am getting the required data from google but not from facebook. Am I doing any wrong here?

PS: I copied the same code from SpringSecurityOAuthService to get the info and made two for respective providers as shown:

```
def getUserDetailsGoogle(googleAccessToken){

    if (provider=='google'){
        def response = oauthService.getGoogleResource(googleAccessToken, 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo')
        def googleResponse
        try {
            googleResponse = JSON.parse(response.body)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error "Error parsing response from Google. Response:\n${response.body}"
            throw new OAuthLoginException('Error parsing response from Google', e)
        }

        return googleResponse
    }
}

def getUserDetailsFacebook(facebookAccessToken){
    def response = oauthService.getFacebookResource(accessToken, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me')
    def user
    try {
        facebookResponse = JSON.parse(response.getBody())
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error "Error parsing response from Facebook. Response:\n${response.body}"
        throw new OAuthLoginException("Error parsing response from Facebook", e)
    }
    if (! facebookResponse?.id) {
        log.error "No user id from Facebook. Response:\n${response.body}"
        throw new OAuthLoginException("No user id from Facebook")
    }
    return facebookResponse
}
```

Comment: did u check facebook documentation?

Comment: Yes, it says to parse the redirect URL, But I guess this has been done by the plugin since it has successfully saved facebook id to my Db

Answer (score 0):

In my Grails 2.5.X app I use pac4j for authenticating with Facebook, Google, etc. by adding these dependencies to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
dependencies {       
    compile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-core:1.6.0',
    compile 'org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:1.6.0'
}
```

The relevant [controller class](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/ie/festivals/security/OauthController.groovy) is shown below. If you want to look at the source of the `OauthService` it calls (or anything else), check out the GitHub repository I've linked to.

```
@Secured(['permitAll'])
class OauthController {

    OauthService oauthService
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService
    UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService

    /**
     * Starts the OAuth authentication flow, redirecting to the provider's Login URL. An optional callback parameter
     * allows the frontend application to define the frontend callback URL on demand.
     */
    def authenticate(String provider) {
        BaseOAuthClient client = oauthService.getClient(provider)
        WebContext context = new J2EContext(request, response)

        RedirectAction redirectAction = client.getRedirectAction(context, true, false)
        log.debug "Redirecting to ${redirectAction.location}"
        redirect url: redirectAction.location
    }

    /**
     * Handles the OAuth provider callback.
     */
    def callback(String provider, String error) {
        WebContext context = new J2EContext(request, response)

        if (!error) {
            try {
                CommonProfile profile = oauthService.getUserProfile(provider, context)
                User registeredUser = userRegistrationService.socialSignIn(profile, provider)

                if (!registeredUser.isAttached()) {
                    // User is trying to register with an OAuth provider (e.g. Twitter, Yahoo), that doesn't provide their
                    // email address so they need to submit a form to supply us with their email
                    render view: '/register/confirmEmail', model: [user: registeredUser]
                    return
                }
                springSecurityService.reauthenticate(registeredUser.username)
                flashHelper.info 'social.login.success': provider
                redirect uri: '/'
                return
            } catch (ex) {
                log.error "Error occurred during callback from OAuth2 provider '$provider'", ex
            }
        } else {
            // Most likely explanation is that the user denied access on the consent screen which is not really an error
            log.warn "Callback from OAuth2 provider '$provider' failed due to error: $error"
        }

        flashHelper.warn 'social.login.fail'
        redirect uri: '/'
    }
}
```

Comment: The plugin was selected by company, so I cannot change that. Please, review my update and provide some insights.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin you're using, but IMO if you're copy-pasting code from the plugin into your app, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think the approach used in my app is preferable because i don't need to change the code to support new oauth providers

Comment: I am using springSecurityOAuth Plugin. It is working for google which means it should work for facebook too. But its not working. Right now I am researching on pac4j. May be I will get some insights.